# SAS Desktop (64 Bit) MAPI Error Sending Email with 32 Bit Outlook

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2016, sas

We have been trying to use MAPI to send from SAS Desktop, when we send we get an error message from Outlook

***Sample Code***

```
options emailsys=mapi
filename mailbox email;
data _null;
File Mailbox to = 'email@address.com' from = 'otraemail@address.com' subject = 'test';
put "Hi"
run;
```

When I run this I get the error

```
“Either there is no default mail client or the current mail client cannot fulfill the messaging request. Please run Microsoft Outlook and set it as the default mail client.”
```

Most of the articles I have found mention the opposite of the issue (64 bit office and 32 bit applications) having issues that get this error. I have checked the Bitness regkey and it is set to "x86", repaired office, checked the MSMAPI32.DLL and MAPI32.DLL files which are referenced in some of the articles with no luck and of course Outlook is already set as the default mail client.

We are using

- Outlook 2016 (32 Bit) / SAS Desktop 64 Bit
- Exchange 2013
- MAPI outlook anywhere (aka RPC over HTTP)
- Outlook is the default mail client

Has anyone else had this issue and know how to resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

Our solution was to install the 32 Bit version of SAS Desktop, it worked straight away. This was also the solution recommended by SAS Support.

We did initially want to get the 64 Bit version to work with 32 Bit Outlook as the 64 Bit version of SAS can use more memory and has performance advantages over the 32 Bit a version.

Installed the 32 Bit & 64 Bit versions on the same pc and they can coexist. If high memory functions are required they can be done in the 64 Bit version and the 32 Bit version used for sending bulk mail, etc